# Make sections count steps

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I'm using `\section` in one of my documents. However, I would like my sections to be numbered in the following way: "Step 1: -----", "Step 2: -----", etc. Is there a simple way to do this with the section command, while still having the steps automatically renumber themselves (i.e. so I can refer to the section numbers with `\ref`)?

Comment: Shall the reference to a section show `Step 1` as well? What about the entry in the toc? What is ----- supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

A version which changes the `\thesection` command to include `Step`. As a result, it should be replaced everywhere. If you don't want that you'll have to change `\thesubsection` to not include `Step`. Also it would lead to problems if you use a ToC, as the width of `Step 1:` would be too wide.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\renewcommand*\thesection{Step \arabic{section}:}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A version with changing the section header and using `cleveref` to change the reference format to `Step ...` etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{section}{step}{steps}
\Crefname{section}{Step}{Steps}

\newcommand{\sectionheadingformat}{%
  Step \thesection: -----\quad% 
}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@seccntformat\@seccntformat
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{#1}{section}%
  \sectionheadingformat%
  \else
  \latex@@seccntformat{#1}%
  \fi
}


\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

 Please see \Cref{foo:sec} or \Cref{other:sec}.

\section{Section} \label{foo:sec}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection} 

\section{Other section} \label{other:sec}

\end{document}
```